# Returning IP and Port in an ASP.NET 5 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I need to make an API in ASP.NET 5 with a "Server" entity that has four attributes:

```
    public class Server
    {
        public Guid ServerId { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Ip { get; private set; }
        public int Port { get; private set; }
    }
```

I'm having difficulties in returning the IP and the Port, because I don't know where and how exactly I should return these values. I thought maybe it could be on "ServersController", but it's also not working with the previous answers from StackOverflow.

Here's a chunk of ServersController's code:

```
    [Route("api/servers")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ServersController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ServerContext _context;

        public ServersController(ServerContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Server>>> GetServers()
        {
            return await _context.Servers.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Server>> GetServer(Guid id)
        {
            var server = await _context.Servers.FindAsync(id);

            if (server == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return server;
        }
```

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Server>> PostServer(Server server)
        {
            _context.Servers.Add(server);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction("GetServer", new { id = server.ServerId }, server);
        }
```

Comment: What does or doesn't work about your code?

Comment: So far it is returning the "ServerId" automatically, the "Name" is returning what I assign in the POST or PUT, and the "Ip" and "Port" return null. But I would like the "Ip" and "Port" to automatically return the values (for example 127.0.0.1 and 8080).

Comment: But why? How? An entity named "Server" won't automagically get its properties assigned by values valid for the current web server. If that's what you want, then you need to assign them yourself. A web server doesn't necessarily know what public IP and port it's accessible on.